# Dismissing UISearchController breaks grouped UITableViewController visual

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UITableViewController` that shows countries group by the alphabet. I added a `UISearchController` in code:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

searchController.searchBar.placeholder = ""
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
definesPresentationContext = true
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

The problem is that when I dismiss the search bar, the UI visual kind of breaks, showing a strange space above the search bar:

[image]

Any ideas why this happens and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding:

```
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

self.definesPresentationContext = true
```